# Reading folder content and some files in it uses way more CPU than C or Rust

Tags: haskell

I have a function reading the content of /proc every second. Surprisingly, its CPU usage in top is around 5%, peak at 8%. But same logic in C or Rust just takes like 1% or 2%. Wondering if this can be improved.

```
import Control.Exception
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad
import Data.Char
import Data.Maybe
import System.Directory
import System.FilePath
import System.Posix.Files
import System.Posix.Signals
import System.Posix.Types
import System.Posix.User
import System.IO.Strict as Strict

watch u limit0s limit0h = do
  listDirectory "/proc/" >>= mapM_ (\fp -> do
    isMyPid' <- maybe False id <$> wrap2Maybe (isMyPid fp u)
    wrap2Maybe (Strict.readFile ("/proc/" </> fp </> "stat")))
  threadDelay 1000000
  watch u limit0s limit0h
  where
    wrap2Maybe :: IO a -> IO (Maybe a)
    wrap2Maybe f = catch ((<$>) Just $! f) (\(_ :: IOException) -> return Nothing)
    isMyPid :: FilePath -> UserID -> IO Bool
    isMyPid fp me = do
      let areDigit = fp >= "0" && fp <= "9"
      isDir <- doesDirectoryExist $ "/proc/" </> fp
      owner <- fileOwner <$> getFileStatus ("/proc" </> fp)
      return $ areDigit && isDir && (owner == me)
```

Comment: On my system, after compiling that with `-O2`, it needs ~1% CPU. I changed the `threadDelay` to `100000` so to make it 10x more expensive, and I got ~7% CPU. Are you compiling that with `-O2`? (I also tried to use bytestrings instead of strings, but it did not have any significant effect, apparently)

Comment: Unrelated: I think your code does not consider pids like `/proc/91` since `"91" > "9"`.

Comment: Yes, with -O2. The CPU usage may relate to how fast the hardware is. I am using a Gen2 i5. Have you tried to compare with top/ps (repeatedly)?

Comment: Ah, yes, did not pay attention on that. I was using `isDigital`, just change to this trying to save some calculation.

Comment: `top` here, once set to 1s updates, reports itself sometimes at 0%, sometimes at 1%, and your code is more steady at 1%. I can't estimate the difference here, but it might be a bit slower.